# Undelete a base in Airtable?

Tags: airtable

I guess I have deleted a base in my AirTable, but I do not remember when I deleted it.

Actually, I am not even sure I indeed deleted it.

Can I see deleted bases and undelete them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the base was deleted within a week, then it could be found in your workspace trash bin.
Otherwise, I don't think it is possible to revive it.